# Can't get text I want on list item click

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to web design.  Javascript/HTML/CSS.  Coming from android.  I have a list which I retrieve from firebase.  I want to click on the list item row and get my name from

```
    <p class= "lead">
```

Which is in the js file
and pass that to my next HTML page.  I kinda managed to do this.

My problem.  Wherever I click on in the box, that is what gets sent to the next page.  Ex: If I click on the user name in the box, that gets sent.  I want no matter where in the box gets clicked to have just the class lead to get sent.

I searched Google all day yesterday and everything I find does the same thing I currently have.

.html file

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

 </head>
 <body>

  <h1>Database</h1>
  <hr/>
    <div id="container" class="list">
      <ul id="toons" class="list-group">
        <!-- Conatct Object li.list-group-item.contact will be added here by js -->
      </ul>
    </div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Firebase Library -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.3/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- Contacts Store JavaScript -->
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

.js file

```
  //create firebase reference
var dbRef = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/");
 var contactsRef = dbRef.child('toons');

  //load older conatcts as well as any newly added one...
  contactsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
    console.log("added", snap.key(), snap.val());
  document.querySelector('#toons')
.innerHTML += contactHtmlFromObject(snap.val());



});

//prepare conatct object's HTML
function contactHtmlFromObject(toons){
  console.log( toons );
  var html = '';
  html += '<li class="list-group-item contact">';
    html += '<div>';
      html += '<p class="lead">'+"john"+'</p>';
      html += '<p>'+"999-000-1234"+'</p>';
       html += '<p><small title="'
            +toons.photoUrl+'">'
            +"User Name: " + toons.userId
            +'</small></p>';
html += '</div>';
  html += '</li>';

  return html;
}
  var cars = document.querySelector(".list");

 cars.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
 var toonName = (e.target.innerHTML);
  alert(toonName);

 window.location = 'toonInfo.html';
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('toon',toonName);

});
```

I had a screenshot of my list but I can't post an img.

Comment: try adding event listener to contact class as there will be many elements with contact class and each will have .lead element.

Comment: you did never define myFunction in your code

Comment: Sorry.  I'll edit and remove that.  That was from some other event listener I was trying.  I've tried a lot of different thing I found online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery (you have it already included in your HTML)

```js
$(".list li").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).find("p.lead").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <p class="lead">A</p>
      <p>444-5555</p>
     </li>
    <li>
      <p class="lead">B</p>
      <p>444-5555</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="lead">C</p>
      <p>444-5555</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  That worked.  Just had to remove the "li"

Comment: I just realized I do still have one problem with this.  Whichever list item I click, I always get the 1st list item "lead"

Comment: That is why you need to put the li, if you don't put the li, $(this) is the .list element and you need to bind the event to the .lead container, in my example is the <li> element, maybe in your code is .contact, try with $(".list .contact")

Comment: When trying either one it does absolutely nothing at all.

Comment: You are inserting <li class="list-group-item contact"> elements into <div id="container" class="list"> inside of the <ul id="toons" class="list-group"> element, right?

Comment: Yes.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try with just $("li.contact") maybe you are adding the <li> outside of the .list element

Comment: Ok, try putting all the $(".list li").on("click") ... code inside of the contactsRef.on("child_added") ... just after   document.querySelector('#toons')
.innerHTML += contactHtmlFromObject(snap.val()); because you are adding the new asynchronous content and that content does not have the event binding, if you put the on click after the html addition, the new elements will be bound to the event